# Efficient way in pandas to do an operation that requires access multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

Is there an efficient way to update each individual row in a DataFrame with values from the row below it in sequence?

The DataFrame contains a sequence of positions to which a vehicle travelled in order. I've added two new columns `next_x` and `next_y`, and want to populate those columns, by row, with the values in the `current_x` and `current_y` column from the row directly beneath. The idea being each row will then contain pairs of coordinates describing a position, and the next position a vehicle travelled.

This is working using `iterrows` but is prohibitively slow over the full dataset.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if int(index) < len(df)-1:
        df['next_x'].iloc[int(index)] = df['current_x'].iloc[(int(index)+1)]
        df['next_y'].iloc[int(index)] = df['current_y'].iloc[(int(index)+1)]
```

I can't figure out a good way to use `apply` - am I missing something?

Comment: Please provide a sample data and the output expected. Refer to this post for cues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df[['next_x', 'next_y']] = df[['current_x', 'current_y']].shift(-1)
```

Comment: Solved exactly by this answer, and handles the last row as well - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for "shift" in pandas.

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(5, 5)),columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
```

df.shift(1) will give you all the rows shifted down by one.

Then you just need something like:

```
df- df.shift(1)
```

Good luck!

Comment: Nice! Quick note - to populate each row with the values of the next row, you'll need `df['next_x'] = df['current_x'].shift(-1)` to shift each column *up* by one place.

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler definitely. A little unclear exactly what the OP wants to do, but I'm sure this would get them on the right track.

Comment: Thanks both, I was putting together some sample data but @PeterLeimbigler was too fast. `df- df.shift(1)` as it is shifts all the data down a row and I only needed the two columns, but this is really useful as well.